# Bing Ads API behind a web proxy

Tags: bing, bing-api

My java client is running on Linux machine and working behind a web proxy (using squid web proxy)

My proxy was configured to be open to the “Service Endpoints” in the Page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-overview-web-service-addresses.aspx
And to the redirect url: https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf

I’m getting the attached error:

```
com.microsoft.bingads.InternalException: Internal BingAds SDK exception has occured
at com.microsoft.bingads.internal.LiveComOAuthService.getAccessTokens(LiveComOAuthService.java:101) ~[microsoft.bingads-10.4.2.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.bingads.internal.OAuthWithAuthorizationCode.requestAccessAndRefreshTokens(OAuthWithAuthorizationCode.java:110) ~[microsoft.bingads-10.4.2.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.bingads.internal.OAuthWithAuthorizationCode.refreshTokensIfNeeded(OAuthWithAuthorizationCode.java:142) ~[microsoft.bingads-10.4.2.jar:na]
```

I'm using Bing Ads API SDK 1.4.2

My question is how what do i need to add to my proxy to make my call success

Answer (score 1):

Are you still observing this issue? For troubleshooting it might help to capture the web traffic using a tool such as Fiddler. You can set the proxy as follows:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8888");
```

For more information, please see the [troubleshooting guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bing-ads-error-handling-guide.aspx#troubleshooting), or feel free to [contact support](http://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/bing-ads-support) anytime.